# Can we used google drive's 'watch' API for polling data? How can we use 'watch' API to track changes?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using changes API to track my G-Drive changes, but it's not giving the complete resource data. Can I use 'watch' API to poll my resources?

**Below is my request for changes API:**

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes?pageToken=46' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <Token>' \
```

**Here's the response:**

```
"changes": [
        {
            "kind": "drive#change",
            "type": "file",
            "changeType": "file",
            "time": "2019-10-10T09:15:12.313Z",
            "removed": false,
            "fileId": "<File_ID>",
            "file": {
                "kind": "drive#file",
                "id": "<File_ID>",
                "name": "shared",
                "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
            }
        }
]
```

But using this, I cannot decide the file is created or updated..

Comment: changes doesnt tell you what happend it just tells you something happend.

Comment: What endpoint are you hitting with this to get this response? Are you using v2 or v3 of the API? `Changes: watch` will give you the ability to find out if a change has occurred but if you want more information the [Activity API](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/) of v2 or the [Drive Activity Report of the Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-drive) may be more helpful to you?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I am using v3 of the API. I have tried to hit Drive activity reports API, but its giving me '401'.

Comment: or can we create any client on google cloud platform, so that any user can access Report API using that client?

Comment: `401` Means you aren't authorised to access the API - the token you're using is either invalid or has expired, or you haven't added the right scopes for the API. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Yes. This client doesn't have access of admin privileges. But whenever I tried to create admin account, it is asking me for domain. I am not sure by creating admin account, am I able to used that client for every other account to start any user's OAUTH flow?

Comment: If you're just tracking changes in your Drive you don't need to impersonate other users. If you need to see changes in other users Drives, then a [Service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a [`Changes` resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes#resource), the response has a specific format.

You can see that the `Changes` has the property `file` that is of type [`Files`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource-representations).

What you want to do is inspect the `Files` resource returned by the change to monitor the state of the file between changes.

Hope this helps!